# Hazelcast client tool for Professional edition

Tags: hazelcast

Any intuitive Hazelcast client tool suggestions to check maps in professional edition? I am trying to identify some problems happening in hazelcast layer where we use professional edition. I couldn't find any good hazelcast client tool for professional edition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hazelcast Management Center, which is free to use for clusters of up to 3 members. You can download it from [here](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/download/#hazelcast-imdg-management-center). You can find its documentation [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/latest/manual/html/index.html). You can check stats of your maps, view/edit their configuration and browse their entries.

Answer (score 1):

There are several official possibilities:

- [Hazelcast Management Center](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/download/#hazelcast-imdg-management-center) - web application
- [Hazelcast Clients](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-clients) - for example the Java one:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-enterprise</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("10.0.0.1");
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
System.out.println(client.getMap("test").get("key"));
client.shutdown();
```

You can also use for instance Groovy shell, which is handy for its tab-completion:

```sh
# start the shell
groovysh -cp hazelcast-enterprise-4.0.jar \
  -e "System.setSecurityManager(null); import com.hazelcast.core.*; import com.hazelcast.client.*"

# and then interactively do whatever you want
hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
hz.getMap("test").get("key");
```

BTW. The Maven artifacts for Enterprise edition are not located in Maven Central repository, but in the Hazelcast one: https://repository.hazelcast.com/release/

```xml
<repository>
    <id>Hazelcast Private Release Repository</id>
    <url>https://repository.hazelcast.com/release/</url>
</repository>
```